# Python & InfluxDB: get most recent measurement

Tags: python, influxdb, measurement

First, some context about my application:

- Databases were created on InfluxDB (in my VM)
- I am already writing in a measurement
- The script runs at a frequency of once per minute

I need to write a Python script to read the database. I want to fetch only the most recent measurement value, not all values.

Here is my code:

```python
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

client = InfluxDBClient(database='test')
client = InfluxDBClient()

rs = cli.query("SELECT * from CoreTemperature")
CoreTemperature = list(rs.get_points(measurement='CoreTemperature'))

print(CoreTemperature)
```

I am stuck because of:

1. The output of this code is: `**NameError: name 'cli' is not defined**`
2. Filtering by measurement and `select * from CoreTemperature` will read all points saved for the measurement, but I only want the most recent value.

Comment: You should use code blocks to format the code snippets you paste. Also it should be obvious but `cli` is supposed to be `client` from `client = InfluxDBClient(database='test') client = InfluxDBClient()`

Comment: If i am not mistaken you need to query with client.query("SELECT last(*) from CoreTemperature group by *")

https://community.influxdata.com/t/influxdb-query-last-row-of-all-series-in-a-measurement/4915/2

Comment: Thks @JasonChia I'm going to use the script using LAST (*)

Answer (score 1):

**The first error** :  `NameError: name 'cli' is not defined` is because you defined the `influxdb` client as `client`, and in the query you are calling it as `cli`

`rs = client.query("SELECT * from CoreTemperature")`

this will resolve this error.

**The second error** will be solved by:

`client.query('SELECT last(<field_name>), time FROM CoreTemperature ')`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the most recent measurement value written to `CoreTemperature`. You can get that using the [`LAST` selector](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#last):

> **LAST()**
>   Returns the field value with the most recent timestamp.

Like this:

```
SELECT LAST(*) FROM CoreTemperature
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning everyone
I reach the target with the following code:

```
>from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

>dbClient = InfluxDBClient()
>loginRecords = dbClient.query('select last(*) from CoreTemperature', 
database='test')
>print(loginRecords)
```

Thanks for all comments and help me!